# minted broke equation numbering in an user-defined environment

Tags: equations

When I load the minted package between amsmath and hyperref, the equation numbering seems to be broken in an environment of mine.

```latex
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newenvironment{hop}[1]{\equation#1\endequation\align}{\endalign}

\begin{document}
    \begin{hop}{ a + b = c }
        c - a = b\\
        c - b = a
    \end{hop}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What cause that behavior? And how can I go back to the one number per line?

This behavior doesn't appear when minted is load somewhere else, but I can't load `minted` after `hyperref` because `csquotes` goes between, and I can't load `minted` before `amsmath` because `amsmath` is part of the class I need to use.
Replacing the parameter with an hard-coded formula doesn't change anything.
The problem seems to come from the `equation` environment, but this seems to be the most suited for my needs.

Comment: The issue is with the `lineno` package.

Comment: Thanks @egreg! But can you elaborate a bit? I can't find any incompatibility between `amsmath` and `lineno` (at least not for equations numbering).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `minted` package is not relevant to the issue: the problem is in how `lineno` redefines `equation`. The processing by `amsmath` gets confused.

Solution:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lineno}

\newenvironment{hop}[1]{\begin{equation}#1\end{equation}\align}{\endalign}

\begin{document}

\begin{hop}{ a + b = c }
c - a &= b+abc+de \\
c - b &= a
\end{hop}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `environ` package to set this up.  It interfers less with the inner environments.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,environ}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewEnviron{hop}[1]{\begin{equation}#1\end{equation}\begin{align}\BODY\end{align}}

\begin{document}
\begin{hop}{ a + b = c }
  c - a = b\\
  c - b = a
\end{hop}
\end{document}
```

Incidentally you have not specified any alignment points `&` in the body.

Comment: About the alignment points in the body, you're right, I totally forgot them in my example. (they are present in the real document though)